# Executing PL/SQL functions from a file

Tags: oracle, plsql, sqlplus

I am using SQL*Plus and have a file called `functions.sql`, which contains 3 PL/SQL functions:

```
create or replace function getcustnamebyid (id number) return varchar2(30)
 is
   ...
 begin
   ...
 end;
/

create or replace function getspcommbyid (id number) return float
 is
   ...
 begin
   ...
/

create or replace function iscommok (comm float) return boolean
 is
   ...
 begin
   ...
 end;
/
```

I'm trying to call these functions in a `driver.sql` program. I have tried the following, but I get a *PL/SQL: ORA-00904: "FUNCTIONS"."GETCUSTNAMEBYID": invalid identifier* error. The two files are in the same directory, how do I call my functions defined in `functions.sql` from `driver.sql`? Would procedures also be called the same way?

**driver.sql:**

```
declare
  name varchar2(30);
  comm float;
  commok boolean;
begin
  select functions.getcustnamebyid(100)
  into name
  from dual;
  dbms_output.put_line('Hi ' || name );
end;
/
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't.

A function is a database object; that means that it's been [compiled on the database](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/overview.htm#LNPLS00103). Before you can use the functions you first need to compile them - you can do this be executing the .sql file you have from SQL*Plus, for example:

```
sqlplus username/password@db @ driver.sql
```

This will create (or replace if they already exist) the functions within your database.

It would also be worth adding the SQL*Plus command [`show errors`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/errors.htm#LNPLS00711) after each function creation, so that if there any errors you can see them.

Comment: So I have to run functions.sql before running driver.sql and there is no way for driver.sql to run functions.sql within itself?

Comment: That's correct @Julio; you need to ensure that the functions exist on the database before you can use them.

Comment: Actually, you could add `@functions.sql` to the beginning of driver.sql (before the `declare`). This is an instruction to SQL*Plus to run the other file. However, you'd still be better off deploying the functions once, rather than re-deploying every time you want to use them.

Comment: It was more of a response to the comments. It is possible to make driver.sql run functions.sql. It won't do what the OP really wanted, but you can certainly call one script from within another.

Answer (score 2):

In PL/SQL, functions must be created within the context that you want to use them. Typically this is done by creating objects in the database, as other answers are suggested. If you're really against creating database objects for some reason, you can actually limit their scope to your PL/SQL block:

```
DECLARE
   FUNCTION getcustnamebyid (id NUMBER)
      RETURN VARCHAR2 IS
   BEGIN
      RETURN NULL;
   END;

   name VARCHAR2 (30);
BEGIN
   name := getcustnamebyid (100);
   DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('Hi ' || name);
END;
/
```

You can't reference functions in another file this way, but it does allow you to use the functions without persisting them. One caveat to this approach is that you will only be able to use the functions in procedural code; SQL can only reference functions created as database objects.

Answer (score 1):

**The source of your problem is your function invocation**

Suppose we create the function, get_hello_world, in the schema, scott (standard example schema).

```
SCOTT@erp> 

  1  CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_hello_world RETURN VARCHAR2
  2  IS
  3  BEGIN
  4    RETURN 'hello world';
  5* END get_hello_world;
SCOTT@erp> /

Function created.

SCOTT@erp> commit;
```

Next we create a driver.sql file.  Here is my example:

```
BEGIN
  dbms_output.put_line(scott.get_hello_world);
END;
```

Next, we want to call it in a driver file:

```
SCOTT@erp> @driver.sql
  4  /
hello world

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

While your new object, `scott.get_hello_world`, is a new database object of type function, we do not qualify our invocation with the word, "function".

You received the error,`PL/SQL: ORA-00904: "FUNCTIONS"."GETCUSTNAMEBYID": invalid identifier`, because the newly compiled database object within the scott schema, `get_hello_world`, is not properly referenced.

Lastly, we can qualify our invocation with the owner, `scott`, or not if we invoke it while using the scott database account.

Answer (score 0):

Late to this party, but you can "include" the file containing some functions and then call on them, for example,

helper_functions.sql

```
procedure Echo(AValue in varchar2) is
begin
  dbms_output.put_line(AValue);
end;
```

driver.sql

```
set serveroutput on
declare
  @@helper_functions.sql
begin
  Echo('hello');
end;
/
```

Output here would be

```
SQL> @@driver.sql
hello

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```